# AngularJS Create a table from an array

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of items and I want to render it as a table with 2 columns.

I did the basic implementation which is rendering with only one column. Any suggestions please?

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in items">
      <td>{{i}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>


var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["12", "22", "34", "657", "129"];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nkarri/9czrqLny/1/

Comment: what are the columns

Comment: Well, add the second column: `<td>{{ whatYouWantToDisplayInTheSecondColumn }}</td>`. But since you're looping on an array of strings, I wonder what you might want to display in the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your HTML only has a single `<td>` element, which you are not repeating. Since there's only 1, you get just 1 column. You'll need to have a nested `ng-repeat` in the `<td>` element in order to get more than 1 column, or explicitly have two `<td>` elements defined in your HTML.

You could try to write something more complicated to try to determine when a new column or row should be created, but I'd simplify things by creating your array into something that will be a little easier to consume: essentially a 2-dimensional array. Here's what I would do instead:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in items">
                <td ng-repeat="column in row">{{column}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.items[0] = ["12", "22"];
    $scope.items[1] = ["34", "657"];
    $scope.items[2] = ["129", null];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bntguybm/

Note that if any of these arrays were to contain more than 2 values, then you would also see extra columns for the rows that contains that data.

An alternative way would be like this, which would guarantee only 2 columns. You would need to create an array of objects for your `items` object. Like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in items">
                <td>{{row.column1}}</td>
                <td>{{row.column2}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.items[0] = {};
    $scope.items[0].column1 = "12";
    $scope.items[0].column2 = "22";
    $scope.items[1] = {};
    $scope.items[1].column1 = "34";
    $scope.items[1].column2 = "657";
    $scope.items[2] = {};
    $scope.items[2].column1 = "129";
    $scope.items[2].column2 = null;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6v1701gx/1/

Answer (score 0):

I googled and figured it out. This is what I came up with using index.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in items" ng-if="$index%7 == 0">
      <td>{{items[$index]}}</td>
      <td>{{items[$index+1]}}</td>
      <td>{{items[$index+2]}}</td>
      <td>{{items[$index+3]}}</td>
      <td>{{items[$index+4]}}</td>
      <td>{{items[$index+5]}}</td>
      <td>{{items[$index+6]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['12', '22', '34', '657', '129', '11', '23', '45', '65', '9', '76', '87', '90', '33', '51'];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nkarri/9czrqLny/2/

Comment: This works, but shows a serious design problem. Instead of having an array of strings, you should have an array of objects, where each object would have named fields: firstName, lastName, whatever. It's much clearer to use `{{user.lastName}}` than `{{items[$index + 1] }}`, isn't it?

Comment: not only the readability aspect; this design has another flaw.  if you inspect the HTML output, you will see 6 empty `tr` in between every "used" one.  `ng-if` causes them to be commented out, but they still exist.